# Wait for the first await to complete before second await -Async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to make the second function to wait until the completion of the first. In the following example, I am not able to achieve it. When exploring about async/await, it was said that the order of execution would be sequential. However, this does not seem to be the case here.

```js
function one() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Hi')
  }, 5000)
}

function two() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Bye')
  }, 2000)
}

async function doAll() {
  await one();
  await two();
}
async function demo() {
  await doAll();
}

demo()
```

**Output**

```
Bye
Hi
```

In this example, since function two involves less time, `'Bye'` is printed before the `'Hi'`. But I am trying to make sure when the first function completes its execution, then it should go to the second.

Comment: `await Promise.all([one, two])` maybe?

Comment: The first function does complete before the second. In fact, both functions complete near instantly, but the timeouts don't.

Comment: `await` works with Promises. Neither of your function return one. `await one()` makes no sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because functions that you defined can't be `await` ed in a sense that they do not return a promise, that can resolve. Instead they complete instantly/"resolve" instantly.

```js
function one() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Hi')
      resolve();
    }, 5000)
  })
}

function two() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Bye')
      resolve();
    }, 2000)
  })
}

async function doAll() {
  await one();
  await two();
}
async function demo() {
  await doAll();
}

demo()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, promise must be:

```
function one() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
       setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('Hi')
          resolve(x);
       }, 5000);
    });
}


function two() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
       setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('Bye')
          resolve(x);
       }, 2000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple issues going on here. First, your functions one() and two() are not async, so they cannot be awaited. Secondly, your test code with the timeout is not an accurate test. The timeout function is not async either, to fix that, I wrapped it in a Promise so we could test with the timeout function.

See snippet:

```js
async function one(){
  await timeout(5000);
  log("Hi");
}

async function two(){
  await timeout(2000);
  log("Bye");
}

async function demo()
{
  await one();
  await two();
}

demo();

function log(logText)
{
  var logNode = document.createTextNode(logText + " ");  
  document.getElementById("log").appendChild(logNode);
}

function timeout(ms)
{
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

```css
#log
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to know that **setTimeout()** runs in a seperate thread and the programm execution, which is in the main thread will not stop even if you make it async.

In order to achieve your requirment you have to call the second function when the timer is completed

```
async function one(){
  await setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log('Hi')
  two() //call the second function when the first timer is completed.
  },5000)
}

function two(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log('Bye')
  },2000)
}
```

Comment: Hi @JonasWilms, can you please elaborate, should i call it a process ??

Answer (score 0):

```
function one() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
     resolve(console.log("hi"))
    }, 5000);
  });
}
function two() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Bye')
  }, 2000)
}
async function asyncCall() {
  var result1 = await one();
  var result2 = await two();
}

asyncCall();
```